How to configure vim-lsp and pylsp in .vimrc?
The following is my .vimrc configuration:
call plug#begin()

" color scheme
Plug 'morhetz/gruvbox'
Plug 'prabirshrestha/vim-lsp'
Plug 'mattn/vim-lsp-settings'

call plug#end()

if executable('pylsp')
    " pip install python-lsp-server
    au User lsp_setup call lsp#register_server({
        \ 'name': 'pylsp',
        \ 'cmd': {server_info->['pylsp']},
        \ 'allowlist': ['python'],
        \ })
endif

When I write Python code, I encounter the E501 error because my line is too long. I found a key pylsp.plugins.pycodestyle.maxLineLength in the python-lsp-server documentation that seems to fix the error. However, I don't know where to configure this key. I hope the .vimrc file can hold all the configurations to reduce the number of configuration files.

fix the E501 error.
know how to configure lsp in .vimrc file.


The idea to minimize configuration files is inherently flawed. You should configure pylsp in its own configuration files because the option you cite is a pylsp option. Running pylsp should give the same results whether or not it's been run from Vim. Likewise, not all project contributors will use Vim with your configuration. They should get the same behavior. You should decouple your problem from Vim.
